# Can a node of a linked list == null?

Tags: java, linked-list

In the solution code for a problem of linked lists, the first few lines look like this.

```
public static void doStuff(IntNode front){
    if(front == null){
        return;
    }
    /* rest of the code */
}
```

Maybe I am confused, but I don't understand how front could possibly be equal to null. front must be of type IntNode, right?

My question is, could that comparison ever run without an error?

Comment: The front will be `null` if your linked list has no elements...

Comment: You can set it to `null` because it is an **Object**.

Comment: @c650 Wouldn't that throw an error though? Would the comparison ever run?

Comment: Ever run?  Yes, it would.  I think a static method is a bad idea.  You want every instance to be independent.

Answer (score 1):

In a linked list, by definition, the final node's `next` pointer will be `null`; that's how you know that you reached the end of the list. Therefore, any method that deals with nodes should expect to get a null node.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider it as a safety check. In case if `front` is null, then whatever you do with that object will raise error.

Also note that, `front` is an object of type `IntNode`, so you can compare an object with `null`. In java, an object variable can be null, so such comparison is valid.

Yes, the comparison is run every time the function is called but if `front` is never null, then the function will execute its regular operation. If `front` is null, then function will return without executing rest of its operations. Rest of the operations mean other statements from the function except the `if` condition.

Comment: Isn't null of type null though? How can you pass a null value as an argument to a function if the function is supposed to take an IntNode?

Comment: Think if you have declared an `IntNode` object but didn't initialize it, then the object is of type `IntNode` but the object is actually `null`. In this case, you need to have a checking in that function. Note that, you are talking about type but I am talking about null object. When you declare an object of a class but don't initialize it, the object is treated as a null object.